# Is there an accessible $\omega$-model of this theory with $\sf ZFC$ inside $\sf ZC$?

Tags: category-theory, set-theory, model-theory

I've once [suggested](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/424508/does-sf-zc-universes-zfcv-meet-mullers-criteria-for-a-founding-theory?) the following theory as a theory that meets [Muller's criteria: page 14](http://philsci-archive.pitt.edu/1372/1/SetClassCat.PDF) for a founding theory of Mathematics. I'll re-exposit it here:

Define an upward membership chain as a nonempty class where for every element there is an element that has the former element among its elements. Formally:

$\operatorname {\in^{\uparrow}} (I) \iff I \neq \emptyset \land \forall i \in I \exists j \in I : i \in j$

A *set* would be defined as a *deep* class, i.e. as an element of an upward membership chain. So:

$\operatorname {set}(x) \iff \exists I: \operatorname {\in^\uparrow}(I) \land x \in I$

Add the Universe axiom stating that a class of all sets exists. Call it $W$.

Let $\sf ZFC^W$ refer to all axioms of $\sf ZFC$ writtin with all quantifiers bounded $\in W$.

Now I proposed the theory: $$ \sf ZC  + Universe + ZFC^W$$

> Is this theory equi-consistent with $\sf ZFC$?

> Can we construct an $\omega$-model of this theory without resorting to any large cardinal property.

Comment: How is "a class of all sets exists" formulated? I suspect the standard definition in ZFC, "there is a class $W=\{x\mid\phi(x)\}$ where for all sets $x$, $\phi(x)$ is true" is trivial, since we can choose any tautology for $\phi$.

Comment: @C7X, the axiom is: **Universe:** $\exists x \forall y (y \in x \iff \operatorname {set}(y))$, then define $W=\{y \mid \operatorname {set}(y)\}$.

Comment: @C7X, the dichotomy here is **deep | shallow**, so sets are the deep classes, while nonsets are the shallow classes. So $W$ is a shallow class. Of course all objects are classes.

Comment: OK, I see now. The statement "for any set $x$ there is an infinite membership chain containing $x$" seems weak, since I believe $V_\omega[X]=\cup_{n<\omega}\mathcal P^n(\{x\})$ suffices. But I don't know how to show $W$ is set-sized in any model of this theory, assuming that it is.

Comment: @C7X, I think you mean the domain of this theory can be $V_\omega [W]$. Correct. I'm coming to think that $W$ can be countable actually! I don't see anything forbidding it from being so? Also, even if we add Ackermann's subset axiom (A subclass of a set is a set), then we can take $W=V_{\kappa+\omega}$ where $\kappa$ is the first worldly cardinal, to be a model of this theory, I suppose?!

Comment: What about powerset restricted to $W$? If we have $\omega\in W$ then we must have $\mathcal P(\omega)\in W$, so $W$ doesn't think it's uncountable. But external countability of $W$ is clear by Lowenheim-Skolem

Comment: Yes, there is no element of $W$ that is a function from $\omega$ to $\mathcal P(\omega)$, but there can be a subclass of $W$ that is not an element of $W$ that is such a function. IF we have the subsets axiom, then I think this would be forbidden, and we need to resort to stages at worldly cardinal heights. I suppose.